# in-app billing: How to retrieve tax (vat, play store commission, etc) applied to each order?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing

With in-app billingn how to retrieve tax (vat, play store commission, etc) applied to each order? To retrieve an order details I call Method: `purchases.subscriptions.get`
[https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/purchases/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/tokens/{token}](https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/%7BpackageName%7D/purchases/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/tokens/%7Btoken%7D)

however I retrieve only basic info such as :

```
{
  "startTimeMillis": "1603453537554",
  "expiryTimeMillis": "1603453841145",
  "autoRenewing": false,
  "priceCurrencyCode": "EUR",
  "priceAmountMicros": "12990000",
  "countryCode": "FR",
  "developerPayload": "",
  "cancelReason": 1,
  "orderId": "<orderId>",
  "purchaseType": 0,
  "acknowledgementState": 0,
  "kind": "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase",
  "obfuscatedExternalAccountId": "<obfuscatedExternalAccountId>"
}
```

There is no info about the VAT applied to the order nor the commission play store took (30% or 15%)